# How can I preview a PR merge result in github before actually merging it?

Tags: git, github

Let's suppose you have a GitHub PR already approved, and you want to merge it. However, it is made of several commits. Let's suppose you want to squash them before merging.

Is there any way of previewing how the git history would end after the the merge-squash operation, before actually doing it?

Comment: You can do it in your local copy of the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the pull request locally and `git merge --squash` it into another branch. The easiest way to check out a pull request locally is using the [`gh` cli](https://cli.github.com/). If you wanted to check out PR #100, you would run:

```
gh pr checkout 100
```

This will create a local branch named after the source branch of the pull request.

You can accomplish the same thing with just `git`. The following would check out PR #100 as `example_branch` locally:

```
git fetch origin pull/100/head:example_branch
```

Once you have a local branch, you can check out a target branch and merge it. For example, if we want to try merging it into `main`:

```
git checkout main
git merge --squash <branch_name>
git commit -m "test sqash merge"
```

Where `<branch_name>` is the branch that contains your pull request.

If you didn't want to modify your `main` branch locally, you could create a temporary branch to test the operation:

```
git checkout -b test_branch main
git merge --squash <branch_name>
git commit -m "test sqash merge"
```

Comment: But after that I will need to push my changes, right? Will GitHub 'realize' that those changes can be pushed because they come from an approved pull request?

Comment: You asked about "previewing" the changes. If you want to manually push these changes you can do that, but it won't close the pull request -- you would need to manually close that. I wouldn't particularly recommend that workflow.